# SELECT from table based on COUNT in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by, having

I have four tables:

```
  PAINTING            GALLERY             ARTIST              PAINTED
- PAINTING_TITLE    - GALLERY_ID        - ARTIST_ID         - PAINTED_CODE
- PAINTING_ID       - GALLERY_NAME      - ARTIST_LAST       - ARTIST_ID
                                        - ARTIST_FIRST      - PAINTING_ID
```

The PAINTED table keeps track of the painting painted by each artist. Some paintings are painted by more than one artist. I want to return a list of the paintings that have been painted by two artists.

```
SELECT
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE AS TITLE, 
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME AS GALLERY
FROM
    PAINTING,
    GALLERY,
    PAINTED
WHERE
        PAINTING.GALLERY_ID = GALLERY.GALLERY_ID
    AND
        PAINTING.PAINTING_ID = PAINTED.PAINTING_ID
GROUP BY
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE,
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME
HAVING
    COUNT(PAINTED.ARTIST_ID) = 2
```

This works, but it does not have the artist's name included in the results. I need the each artist's name to be listed along the gallery name and artwork name, each of which will appear twice, but once with a different artist.

I'm using Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE AS TITLE, 
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME AS GALLERY,
    ARTIST.ARTIST_FIRST & " " & ARTIST.ARTIST_LAST
FROM
    PAINTING,
    GALLERY,
    PAINTED,
    ARTIST,
WHERE
        PAINTING.GALLERY_ID = GALLERY.GALLERY_ID
    AND
        PAINTING.PAINTING_ID = PAINTED.PAINTING_ID
    AND
        ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = PAINTED.ARTIST_ID
GROUP BY
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE,
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME
HAVING
    COUNT(PAINTED.ARTIST_ID) = 2
```